# Rollover Popup in fluid layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a rollover popup on click of some picture links on a page as shown below..

[image]

In the above case, the popup will be shown on click of each of the 6 links..

Now I know this can be done by using position:absolute in the CSS and accordingly setting it for fixed layouts...

But in my case, I have a fluid layout (all in %) and the layout shrinks/expands as the browser is resized..So I wanted to know how I can create the popup in such a way that even if the browser gets resized, the positioning of the popup does not get affected (relatively speaking)

**Again please remember, I cannot use fixed values at all like top:10px;bottom:10px...I can only use top:10%;bottom:10%**

Comment: put it up on jsfiddle so we can play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the popups and picture links in some divs. Set `position: relative` to the wrapper div and play with `position: absolute` on the popup element. This way the top and left attributes will be offset to the wrapper div, not the document.

JsFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/VirusZ/5YDLU/

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position

Comment: So can I use just one <div> for the popup and position it dynamically...How do I set it to the top/center of the image which is clicked (like I have show in my image)..

Comment: Beat me to it... Here's another fiddle that demonstrates the centering. You must have a fixed width on your menu for this to work. http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/SagY2/

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle example. If you offset the position relative to the bottom of the div it will appear above the image (on the top) no matter the number of list items.

Comment: Thanks again....The only thing I wanted to clarify is how well will this work for %-based layouts...As i said, I cannot use px values for "top","left", etc ...Also the popup should adjust itself as the browser is resized...

Comment: As long as you keep your % consistent it should not be a problem. Dimensions set in % for the popup will also be relative to the wrapper div. Resize the result area to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/VirusZ/5YDLU/5/

Comment: Hey...I just tried to implement the same on my page...I just realized that I couldn't use it on my page, as the popup gets cropped bcoz of some divs with overflow:hidden that I have used...Also I cannot remove those overflow:hidden divs...So is there any other way like positioning based on click pos of cursor or something of that sort..

Comment: You could add a buffer zone with paddings and negative margins, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/VirusZ/5YDLU/7/

Comment: SO sorry to necropost, but is there a way to do this, except with links instead of images? Simply replacing the images with links didn't work